# When I make my image a link it messes up my positioning - how do I prevent this

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am making a webpage which has large text to the left and 2 images to the right: My code:

```
<section id="cover">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <br>
                    <h1>EVER THOUGHT ABOUT ACTING?</h1>
                    <br>
                </div>
                    
                <div class="col-md-4 centre_text">
                    <img src="public/img/red.png" alt="Take the red pill" >
                    <img src="public/img/blue.png" alt="Take the blue pill" >
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to make the images clickable elements, it moves the content of the DIV to the left (below the text Div).

So basically when I do this

```
            <a href="#"><img src="public/img/red.png" alt="Take the red pill" ></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="public/img/blue.png" alt="Take the blue pill" ></a>
```

This causes the images to move to the bottom left.

I would like my images to stay as they are, after I have made them links. Can anybody advise how to do this? I tried removing my 'centre_text' class and also tried sizing the image, but neither of these made a difference.

Many thanks

[Site as it should display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQKsw.png)

[Site when I make the images links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6uUQ.png)

I have attached some pics.

THis is my CSS (taking into account Amirs answer)

```
.centre_text{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            padding-left: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            }

.centre_text a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I should have added  - I am using the bootstrap 5 framework.

Comment: You'll need to demonstrate the problem in a [mcve]

Comment: Please tag your question with the appropriate version of Bootstrap

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. Also, is your screen size `md` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tags (`<a>`) are inline elements by default, while images (`<img>`) are inline-block

Add this to your CSS

```css
.centre_text a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Note that sometimes `inline-block` elements don't align properly vertically. You can fix this by setting vertical alignment (`vertical-align`)

Comment: Many thanks for your help Amir.  Frustratingly though, this seems not to have made a difference.  I have updated the original question with the CSS (and your answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
  .centre_text{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding-left: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        }

     .centre_text a {
         display: inline-block;
        }
```